# How to build lazy lists with defined generators and is there a "takeWhile" alternative?

Tags: raku

I am reading through [perl6intro on lazy lists](http://perl6intro.com/#_lazy_lists) and it leaves me confused about certain things.

Take this example:

```
sub foo($x) {
  $x**2
}

my $alist = (1,2, &foo ... ^ * > 100);
```

will give me `(1 2 4 16 256)`, it will square the same number until it exceeds 100. I want this to give me `(1 4 9 16 25 .. )`, so instead of squaring the same number, to advance a number `x` by 1 (or another given "step"), `foo x`, and so on.

Is it possible to achieve this in this specific case?

Another question I have on lazy lists is the following:
In Haskell, there is a [takeWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) function, does something similar exist in Perl6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you could write a Perl 6 equivalent of Haskell's `takewhile`.

```perl6
sub take-while ( &condition, Iterable \sequence ){
  my \iterator = sequence.iterator;

  my \generator = gather loop {
    my \value = iterator.pull-one;
    last if value =:= IterationEnd or !condition(value);
    take value;
  }

  # should propagate the laziness of the sequence
  sequence.is-lazy
  ?? generator.lazy
  !! generator
}
```

I should probably also show an implementation of `dropwhile`.

```perl6
sub drop-while ( &condition, Iterable \sequence ){
  my \iterator = sequence.iterator;

  GATHER: my \generator = gather {

    # drop initial values
    loop {
      my \value = iterator.pull-one;

      # if the iterator is out of values, stop everything
      last GATHER if value =:= IterationEnd;

      unless condition(value) {
        # need to take this so it doesn't get lost
        take value;

        # continue onto next loop
        last;
      }
    }

    # take everything else
    loop {
      my \value = iterator.pull-one;
      last if value =:= IterationEnd;
      take value
    }
  }

  sequence.is-lazy
  ?? generator.lazy
  !! generator
}
```

These are only just-get-it-working examples.

It could be argued that these are worth adding as methods to lists/iterables.

You could (but probably shouldn't) implement these with the sequence generator syntax.

```perl6
sub take-while ( &condition, Iterable \sequence ){
  my \iterator = sequence.iterator;
  my \generator = { iterator.pull-one } …^ { !condition $_ }
  sequence.is-lazy ?? generator.lazy !! generator
}
```

```perl6
sub drop-while ( &condition, Iterable \sequence ){
  my \end-condition = sequence.is-lazy ?? * !! { False };
  my \iterator = sequence.iterator;

  my $first;
  loop {
    $first := iterator.pull-one;
    last if $first =:= IterationEnd;
    last unless condition($first);
  }

  # I could have shoved the loop above into a do block
  # and placed it where ｢$first｣ is below

  $first, { iterator.pull-one } … end-condition
}
```

If they were added to Perl 6/Rakudo, they would likely be implemented with Iterator classes.
( I might just go and add them. )

---

A direct implementation of what you are asking for is something like:

```perl6
do {
  my $x = 0;
  { (++$x)² } …^ * > 100
}
```

Which can be done with state variables:

```perl6
{ ( ++(state $x = 0) )² } …^ * > 100
```

And a state variable that isn't used outside of declaring it doesn't need a name.
( A scalar variable starts out as an undefined Any, which becomes 0 in a numeric context )

```perl6
{ (++( $ ))² } …^ * > 100
{ (++$)² } …^ * > 100
```

If you need to initialize the anonymous state variable, you can use the defined-or operator `//` combined with the equal meta-operator `=`.

```perl6
{ (++( $ //= 5))² } …^ * > 100
```

---

In some simple cases you don't have to tell the sequence generator how to calculate the next values.
In such cases the ending condition can also be simplified.

```perl6
say 1,2,4 ...^ 100
# (1 2 4 8 16 32 64)
```

The only other time you can safely simplify the ending condition is if you **know** that it will stop on the value.

```perl6
say 1, { $_ * 2 } ... 64;
# (1 2 4 8 16 32 64)

say 1, { $_ * 2 } ... 3;
# (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the takeWhile and dropWhile example implementations. About the generator: So am I right to assume that it is not possible to use a named function in this case? Like `{ foo(++$x) } ...^ * > 100`

Comment: @learningProgged Why wouldn't it be possible? That isn't really the way it was meant to be used, but take that with a grain of salt as I've probably misused that feature more than anyone else for writing code golf entries. You may want to mark it as lazy in some cases `({ foo ++$ } ...^ * > 100).lazy`

Answer (score 6):

> I want this to give me (1 4 9 16 25 .. )

The easiest way to get that sequence, would be:

```
my @a = (1..*).map(* ** 2);  # using a Whatever-expression
my @a = (1..*).map(&foo);    # using your `foo` function
```

...or if you prefer to write it in a way that resembles a Haskell/Python list comprehension:

```
my @a = ($_ ** 2 for 1..*);  # using an in-line expression
my @a = (foo $_ for 1..*);   # using your `foo` function
```

While it is possible to go out of one's way to express this sequence via the `...` operator (as [Brad Gilbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41200424/1160124) and [raiph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195926/1160124) demonstrate), it doesn't really make sense, as the purpose of that operator is to generate sequences where each element is derived from the previous element(s) using a consistent rule.

Use the best tool for each job:

- **If a sequence is easiest to express iteratively** *(e.g. Fibonacci sequence)*:
  Use the `...` operator.
- **If a sequence is easiest to express as a closed formula** *(e.g. sequence of squares)*:
  Use `map` or `for`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want this to give me (1 4 9 16 25 .. )

```
my @alist = {(++$)²} ... Inf;
say @alist[^10]; # (1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)
```

The `{…}` is an arbitrary block of code. It is invoked for each value of a sequence when used as the LHS of [the `...` sequence operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_...).

The `(…)²` evaluates to the square of the expression inside the parens. (I could have written `(…) ** 2` to mean the same thing.)

The `++$` returns `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 …` by combining a pre-increment `++` (add one) with [a `$` variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_$_Variable).

> In Haskell, there is a takeWhile function, does something similar exist in Perl6?

Replace the `Inf` from the above sequence with the desired end condition:

```
my @alist = {(++$)²} ... * > 70;    # stop at step that goes past 70
say @alist; # [1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]

my @alist = {(++$)²} ...^ * > 70;   # stop at step before step past 70
say @alist; # [1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64]
```

Note how the `...` and `...^` variants of the sequence operator provide the two variations on the stop condition. I note in your original question you have `... ^ * > 70`, not `...^ * > 70`. Because the `^` in the latter is detached from the `...` it has a different meaning. See Brad's comment.

Comment: `... ^ * > 70` is the same as `… (^*) > 70` so it is effectively the same as `* > 70`