# In Raku, doesn't routine first return Nil when no values match?

Tags: list, boolean, raku

---

According to [**Raku documentation**](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#routine_first), routine `first` returns `Nil` when no values match.  However, why doesn't the line `say ($result === Nil) ;` (below) print `True`?

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my @myNumberList is Array[Int] = [2, 2, 5, 7] ;
  my $result = @myNumberList.first( {$_ > 10} ) ;
  say '$result' ;
  say $result ;
  say $result.WHAT ;
  say ($result === Nil) ;
  } # end sub MAIN
```

Program output is …

```
$result
(Any)
(Any)
False
```

---

##### Update

My goal was to determine whether a list or an array contains one or more elements satisfying a given predicate.  In the following sample program, the `elems` routine returns a value that is greater than 0 if and only if the given list or array contains at least one element satisfying the predicate given in the corresponding call to `grep` .

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my $myList = (2, 2, 5, 7) ;
  say '$myList' ;
  say $myList ;
  say $myList.WHAT ;

  my $grepResult1 = $myList.grep( * > 10, :p ) ;
  say '$grepResult1' ;
  say $grepResult1 ;
  say $grepResult1.WHAT ;
  say ($grepResult1.elems <= 0) ;

  my $grepResult2 = $myList.grep( * > 4, :p ) ;
  say '$grepResult2' ;
  say $grepResult2 ;
  say $grepResult2.WHAT ;
  say ($grepResult2.elems <= 0) ;

  my @myArray = [2, 2, 5, 7] ;
  say '@myArray' ;
  say @myArray ;
  say @myArray.WHAT ;

  my $grepResult3 = @myArray.grep( * > 10, :p ) ;
  say '$grepResult3' ;
  say $grepResult3 ;
  say $grepResult3.WHAT ;
  say ($grepResult3.elems <= 0) ;
  } # end sub MAIN
```

Program output is …

```
$myList
(2 2 5 7)
(List)
$grepResult1
()
(Seq)
True
$grepResult2
(2 => 5 3 => 7)
(Seq)
False
@myArray
[2 2 5 7]
(Array)
$grepResult3
()
(Seq)
True
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question that appears to be (somewhat) addressed on the ["Traps To Avoid"](https://docs.raku.org/language/traps) documentation page. See the specific subheading: ["Assignment of Nil can produce a different value, usually 'Any' "](https://docs.raku.org/language/traps#Assignment_of_Nil_can_produce_a_different_value,_usually_Any). Also, the Raku documentation page on [class Nil](https://docs.raku.org/type/Nil) .

The short answer--as near as I can surmise--is to use smartmatching with a Junction ***on the right-hand-side***:

Sample Code:

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my @myNumberList is Array[Int] = [2, 2, 5, 7] ;
  my $result = @myNumberList.first( {$_ > 10} ) ;
  say '$result' ;
  say $result ;
  say $result.WHAT ;

"\n".say;

  say  Nil ~~ all($result);  #True
  say  Nil ~~ any($result);  #True
  say  Nil ~~ one($result);  #True
  say  Nil ~~ none($result); #False

"\n".say;

  my $result2 = @myNumberList.first( {$_ < 10} ) ;
  say  Nil ~~ all($result2);  #False
  say  Nil ~~ any($result2);  #False
  say  Nil ~~ one($result2);  #False
  say  Nil ~~ none($result2); #True

  } # end sub MAIN
```

Returns:

```
$result
(Any)
(Any)


True
True
True
False


False
False
False
True
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the above code (and clean up your output) using `.defined`:

1. for `result` above (where there are no matching values) `say $result if $result.defined;` returns nothing;
2. for `result2` above (where the first matching value is 2) `say $result2 if $result2.defined;` returns `2`.

For further reading to understand how the smartmatch solution(s) posted above came about, look at the following Github issue: ["In general, the left side of ~~ should not be auto-threading"](https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/297).

[Also, (at the risk of confusing the reader), take a look at the **Raku** code posted on the following **Perl5** doc page: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Differences-from-Raku ].

**ADDENDUM:** For a discussion on the *'do-something-only-if-defined'* idiom in Raku, see Damian Conway's talk ["On The Shoulders of Giants"](https://youtu.be/Nq2HkAYbG5o?t=1326), which includes his code for a user-defined `?=` ("assign-if-defined") operator.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Yes, `first` returns `Nil` when no values match. One way to get what you want is to bind the result (with `:=`) instead of assigning it (with `=`).

## A simple solution

Switch from the assignment operator (`=`) to the [binding operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_:=) (`:=`):

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my @myNumberList is Array[Int] = [2, 2, 5, 7] ;
  my $result := @myNumberList.first( {$_ > 10} ) ;     # <-- Add colon
  say '$result' ;
  say $result ;
  say $result.WHAT ;
  say ($result === Nil) ;
  } # end sub MAIN
```

displays:

```
$result
Nil
Nil
True
```

## What's happening in your original code

> In Raku, doesn't routine `first` return `Nil` when no values match?

Yes. That's not the problem.

`Nil` represents "Absence of a value ...".¹

So don't think of it as a value like, say, `42` or `'string'` or an empty list².

Assigning `Nil` to a variable resets the variable's value to its default:

```
my $foo is default(42) = Nil;
say $foo; # 42
```

The *default* default value for a variable is `Any`³, so:

```
my $bar = Nil;
say $bar; # (Any)
```

That's what happened in your original code.

## Options

You could set `$result`'s default to `Nil` so that when you *assign* `Nil` to it you get what you want:

```
my $result is default (Nil) = @myNumberList.first( {$_ > 10} ) ;
```

But that's cumbersome. And seldom desirable.

Usually, if you want a variable to *keep* a `Nil`, you just *bind* it instead of assigning it:

```
my $qux := Nil;      # <-- use `:=` instead of `=`
say $qux; # Nil
```

<strike>Just set your mental model to match what Raku's doing and you'll find it's all really simple.</strike>⁴

## Footnotes

¹ Per [its doc](https://docs.raku.org/type/Nil), `Nil` is "Absence of a value or a benign failure". The "Absence of a value" aspect applies if you call `first` to find the first value in some list of values that matches a predicate, but there were no such values. The "benign failure" applies if you call `first` and it encounters some error condition and either decides it's benign but ought terminate its processing, or throws an exception that gets handled such that further evaluation continues with the code that receives the value returned by `first`.

As you read this footnote you might think these two cases would best be handled separately. But if you think further you will hopefully see that they work beautifully as two sides of the same coin. Any called code can return `Nil`, and calling code knows that the result of the call is an absence of a value. This may be due to entirely normal processing which yields no value, or due to processing that encountered an error, but that error was either considered by the called code as so benign as to not be worth reporting to the caller other than by returning `Nil`, or resulted in an exception being thrown that was subsequently handled to clear the error condition -- thus returning processing to normal status. Raku's elegant and practical `Nil` is yet another reason why I ❤ Raku.

² An empty list is a still a value. Albeit an empty one.

³ `Any` is a type. When treated as a "value" it's a [type object](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#Type_objects) representing an undefined value of type `Any` or a subtype thereof. It makes a natural default default value for variables and parameters.

⁴ I suspect I offended folk by writing my "Just ..." sentence. I thought about deleting or editing it, but then folk wouldn't have context for @jubilatious1's comment and my point, which I think is a good one that @jubilatious1 misunderstood, would be lost. I'm leaving it in with this footnote for now in the hope someone will engage with me if they think it is a problem and/or if it would be a good idea for me to remove it or, conversely, unstrike it.

Comment: *"Just set your mental model to match what Raku's doing and you'll find it's all really simple."* The OP is trying to figure out what Raku is doing. If you're going to go into so-called "absence-of-values", then that necessarily would require discussion of the empty List, denoted with the keyword `Empty` or simply the empty parens `()`. Then...we'll see isn't all so simple!

Comment: "The OP is trying to figure out what Raku is doing." Yes. And imo that's not so simple. And this is so even if what Raku is doing is really simple. "If you're going to go into so-called "absence-of-values"" Well, I didn't go into that so much as the Raku design did, and `Nil` is a central part of that. "then that necessarily would require discussion of the empty `List`" Imo it's not necessary *to understand Raku's model*. An empty `List` is a value, a `List`, albeit an empty one. "isn't all so simple!" Imo Raku's model is but human models aren't. Surmise yields surprise until we let go! 

Comment: If a value and/or values is/are truly `Nil`, meaning you have no knowlege of it/them, (and/or  it/they are `NA` "not-available"), then how can you say with any certainty that you have one-and-only-one `Nil` element?

Comment: "If a value and/or values is/are truly `Nil`, meaning you have no knowlege of it/them, (and/or it/they ..." What "value", "it", "them", or "they"? Imagine the universe does not exist. There is nothing at all. `Nil` represents this notion of nothingness. There's nothing to count. There's not one-and-only-one this or that. There's not zero of "them". There's not even none. There's just an absence of anything. Now consider code that *expects* to be given a "value". `Nil` represents the concept "I'm sorry, there is no value, there is nothing for you, please handle this situation as you see fit".

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706668/227738